# Cant' navigate through the pages of a survey using surveyJS

Tags: angular, typescript, surveyjs

I'm using the library SurveyJS in my angular project. I need to be able to navigate through pages programmatically.
My first attempt was:

```
this.survey.currentPageNo = 5;  //navigate to page 5.
```

Unfortunately it didn't work. So I checked the documentation about [this field](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/survey-data-model#currentPageNo) and it states that:

> A zero-based index of the current page in the visiblePages array.

So, I'm only allowed to navigate throught visible pages. My survey has 10 pages, so this.survey.pages.length = 10, but this.survey.visiblePages.length = 1, it means that only the first page is visible.
According to the documentation, I should be able to set the page visibility by adding a "visible" : true to the page configuration.
So in my case it would be something like:

```
"pages": [
    {
        "elements": [
            //list of elements
        ],
        "visible": true,
        "name": "page1"
    },

    {
        "elements": [
            //list of elements
        ],
        "visible": true,
        "name": "page2"
    }
]
```

but visiblePages.length is still 1... What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please share a stackblitz or more code with the basic issue reproducible!

Comment: Have you tried `this.survey.currentPageNo = this.survey.pages[5];` as per [currentPage](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/survey-data-model#currentPage) docs?